# Replication MySQL & MS SQL

Tags: mysql

How make replication between MySQL and MS SQL server 2005. I want flow data from MySQL to MS SQL server, when ever any changes makes in MySQL.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a SSIS procedure to do this is not difficult if you're willing to do it as a "batch" process. Replicating in real-time has caused our SQL Server to burp big time. We now do a nightly process that copies the data from one server to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try symmetricDS http://www.symmetricds.org/. it is supporting DB sync between different DB and ofcourse, it is supporting MySql & MsSql sync.

you can study and set the configuration as per your needs. it can support the following sync

- One way sync - this option is supposed for your case
- Two way sync

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of linking to external resources wholesale, but there's a [TechRepublic blog](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=112) that implements this exact feat, although it's decidedly non-trivial.

Then again, this is (quite frankly) a bit of an unusual requirement.